# Why does the sample dataset change the speed of the model prediction?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, object-detection, random-forest

I've been playing around with sklearn randomForestClassifier and there is something i do not understand.

I did create a model that classifies each pixel depending if it corresponds to the object or not, in this case, a pear. Something like this:

[image]

To train this model, i used this three images:

[image]

Now comes the thing, i've created two diferent models, each one using a different labeled mask for the same training images:

model 1:

[image]

model 2:

[image]

Both models have an acceptable accuracy, but the problem here is the first model takes around 0.5second to make prediction for 10 new images while model 2 takes around 4seconds to make prediction for the same 10 images. How is that possible?

EDIT with code and more info as @TYZ suggested

```py
def train_model(image_path, labeled_image_path,  test_split=0.3):
    train_img = cv2.imread(image_path) #Load training image
    train_img = cv2.cvtColor(train_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #Convert BGR to RGB
    train_img = train_img[:, :, 2] #Only take the GREEN channel (Try for each channel and select the best)

    df = generate_features(train_img) #Create a dataFrame containing all features

    train_img_labeled = cv2.imread(labeled_image_path)
    train_img_labeled = cv2.cvtColor(train_img_labeled, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #Load labeled image
    df["Labels"] = train_img_labeled.reshape(-1)

    Y = df["Labels"].values
    X = df.drop(labels=["Labels"], axis=1)

    # Split the data into train and test
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=test_split, random_state=20)

    #Create new model
    from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
    model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 5, random_state = 25, max_depth=1, n_jobs=1)

    # Train the model
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    return model
```

```py
def test(model):
    
    image_paths = ["test/scaled/test_1.jpeg", "test/scaled/test_2.jpeg", "test/scaled/test_3.jpeg", "test/scaled/test_4.jpeg", "test/scaled/test_5.jpeg", "test/scaled/test_6.jpeg", "test/scaled/test_7.jpeg",
    "test/scaled/test_8.jpeg", "test/scaled/test_9.jpeg", "test/scaled/test_10.jpeg"]
        
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    
    for image_path in image_paths:
        start_time = time.time()
        result = calculate_model_output(model, image_path, show=False)
    
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time()-start_time))
```

[image]

Comment: You will have to provide more information for us to be able to help you. Please provide a minimum reproducible example with your code, data, or even the models you have trained so that we can reproduce the difference in prediction time.

Comment: Check the average depth of the trees in the two models; maybe your second model ended up growing deeper trees on average.  (And perhaps it's best to measure the depth of your test samples; probably the easiest way to do this is to access the underlying `DecisionTreeClassifier` objects and use their `decision_path` method.)

Comment: @TYZ Original post edited with more info.

Comment: @BenReiniger I have now updated the post with code and more info, as you can see i created the model with max_depth = 1 in both cases.

Comment: With only 5 trees of depth 1, I'd be surprised if prediction took any significant amount of time; loading the images may well take longer.  Are these timings consistent?  Any difference if you change the order of the tests?

Comment: @BenReiniger Also, when i use the decision_path method on both my models for the same test image, i get the same result. https://imgur.com/a/k6HBEAw.  And no, there is no difference if i change the order of the tests. https://imgur.com/a/LtBQVzf

Comment: Those (probably) aren't the same, they're just of the same shape and with the same total number of entries, which is to be expected now that I know your trees are all depth 1:  each row (31212 of them) is in 5 trees and passes through exactly 2 nodes of each tree (the root and one or the other leaf), and 31212*5*2=312120 "stored elements".  But yes, depth=1 disproves my first hypothesis so this won't help much.